# Adding a unique index with a where constraint that includes datetimes

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table, `voucher_redemption`, which has a `user_id` column and an `inserted_at` column, whose type is timestamp with timezone.

I'm trying to apply a unique index to only allow one redemption per user per 24 hours, and I am trying this:

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX
  one_redemption_per_user_per_day
ON
  voucher_redemption (user_id)
WHERE
  (inserted_at AT TIME ZONE 'UTC')
BETWEEN
  ((now() - INTERVAL '24 HOURS') AT TIME ZONE 'UTC')
AND
  (now() AT TIME ZONE 'UTC')
;
```

When I run this, I receive the following:

> (Postgrex.Error) ERROR 42P17 (invalid_object_definition)
> functions in index predicate must be marked IMMUTABLE

According to other posts I've seen online, this is because some timestamps given are not in UTC, but as far as I can see they are.

How can I achieve what I'm trying to?

Thanks in advance

Comment: `now()` is the epitome of a function which is not immutable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your result is because the `now()` function in not immutable. It accesses the server time - which is not 'from the parameters'. You **cannot create a unique constraint** using it. You can create  trigger to effectively accomplish the same. (see [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/Hk4U9efn))

```
create or replace function validate_voucher_redemption()
   returns trigger 
   language plpgsql
as $$
begin 
   if exists (select null
                from voucher_redemption 
               where user_id = new.user_id
                 and inserted_at at time zone 'UTC'+ interval '24 hour' > now() at time zone 'UTC'
             ) 
      then raise exception 'Cannot redeem a second voucher within 24 hours.';  
      else return new; 
   end if;
end; 
$$;

create trigger validate_voucher_redemption_bir
      before insert on voucher_redemption
       for each row 
       execute function validate_voucher_redemption();
```

NOTE: Everything is in time zone 'UTC' however, this is **not** required.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to write this out. Now you state now() isn't immutable it seems pretty obvious.. 

When running this I get `cannot insert multiple commands into a prepared statement`. Brief googling tells me I need to split a query to resolve this.. is it the `select from where` part?

Thanks again!

Comment: What query? The trigger and the function are a one time ddl. Any query should just be your insert statement. Update the question with the query and complete error message.

Comment: The app I'm using (an elixir / phoenix app) was apparently executing these incorrectly, applying these directly to the DB worked, thanks again